# Compress avro files to gzip (.gz) compression

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, gzip, avro

I'm a newbie to avro and .gzip file. I'm trying to compress the avro file to get faster file loading time from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery. And I've already tried to googling but I don't get the answer. Please help me on how to compress avro files to gzip (.gz) compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Avro format can't be used in combination with GZIP compression. To compress Avro data, use the bq command-line tool or the API and specify one of the supported compression types for Avro data: DEFLATE or SNAPPY.

Refrence:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro

Comment: This is not entirely true, it can be used - but it is not recommended as Snappy is specifically suitable for avro